# Conditions in Page Layout

Tags: 2013, content-type, page-layout, migration, pages

I m working on requirement where I need to create page layout for migrated pages from old system. I have to have only one page layout. The migrated pages must have same fields as they were in old system. But the newly created pages based on same layout must not have some of the fields and the editors don't want to see those fields when they create/edit new pages. How can I achive it? I have created Page Layout inside VS 2012, Content Type and added content type to the page layout. I used Powershell to migrate the old pages to the new system. But editors see all fields when they create/edit new pages.

Comment: I understand the problem. But it sounds like you should aim at convincing the client that using one single page layout, with different fields depending on if the content is migrated or not, is not such a great idea. Is there any particular reason why you are not allowed to have two different page layouts and content types?

Comment: I have to talk to the client, but haven't find the right person yet. I think the only reason is they don't want to have too much content types and page layouts to make them confused.

Comment: What you could do is: create a migration content type and a post-migration content type, do the migration and then remove the migration content type from pages library, and remove the migration layout from available page layouts?